# Путь к скрипту, из которого отправляются письма [Linux]

Tags: email, sendmail, логирование

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие настройки и где необходимо включить, чтобы отразить путь к скрипту, из которого отправляются письма. Логирование обращения php к mail уже включено, необходимо также чтобы и другие скрипты логировались.

Цель - отловить скрипт, через который рассылается спам.

Comment: вероятно, перед вами стоит какая-то более глобальная задача: например: с вашей машины рассылается спам и вам нужно «отловить» виновника. если так и есть, внесите, пожалуйста, коррективы в текст вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: Да, так и есть.

Comment: я подразумевал: больше подробностей. например, работает ли на вашей машине smtp-сервер, ведётся ли логирование его работы, и нет ли в этих логах следов рассылки спама. например, проверяли ли вы docroot на подозрительные файлы, например, с помощью [яндексовского *manul*-а.](http://www.yandex.ru/promo/manul)